# How to access to an array of arrays using python APIs in C module

Tags: python, c, arrays

I need to access to an array of arrays which is passed from python to a C module. For example, suppose an array of arrays "A" is created in python as follow:

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import rand
from geoms import *
A=empty((1,2),dtype=object)
A[0,0]=rand(3,3)
A[0,1]=rand(5,5)
gm_unique_all(A)
```

where geoms is the C module which is setup and imported in python and gm_unique_all is a method of that.
I do not know how to access to each sub-array of input array "A" through python APIs for C. I would be thankful if everybody could kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it's done something like this:

```
void processMatrix(PyObject *mat) {
    Py_ssize_t r, c;

    if (!PySequence_Check(mat))
        ; // mat is not a sequence

    for (r=0; r<PySequence_Length(mat); ++r) {
        PyObject *row = PySequence_GetItem(mat, r);

        if (!PySequence_Check(row))
            ; // row is not a sequence

        for (c=0; c<PySequence_Length(row); ++c) {
            PyObject *obj = PySequence_GetItem(row, c);
            // process obj
        }
    }

}
```